# how to serialize and deserialize over two different assembly?

Tags: c#, serialization, binaryformatter

This is a **C# project**. I am using **BinaryFormatter** as the serializer and deserializer for my applications.
Because there are two application and the **assembly names are different from each other**, I am using a **serialization binder** to solve the issue on finding types.
but I still get an error which is :

`Unable to find assembly 'GameServer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.`

and this is my serialization binder code :

```
    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        if (assemblyName.Contains("GameServer"))
        {
            assemblyName = "Assembly-CSharp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=12345";
        }
        return Type.GetType(typeName);
    }
```

in the above code, i just check if an assembly named "GameServer" found, then rename it to the local assembly name.
am i missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, the only "good" answer here is "don't use `BinaryFormatter`", followed closely by "really, don't use `BinaryFormatter`". There are [many good reasons that it is considered deprecated in .NET Core / .NET 5+](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2020/03/why-do-i-rag-on-binaryformatter.html), and this minor inconvenience of matching similar types: didn't even make that list! (Btw, you can avoid having to do that by moving your DTO types to a library assembly that both other projects reference).

Note: for *virtually any other serializer* - JSON, xml, protobuf, etc - it would already "just work": the types being in different assemblies wouldn't remotely matter. So frankly, the best advice here is simply: "change serializer".

Comment: slowly, i am planning to change my serializer to json(newtonsoft). not even protobuf or any binary formatters. cause of stability.Thanks.

Comment: @aidin FWIW is in the same category as Newtonsoft when it comes to stability; the only difference is that the format isn't human readable

Comment: I more like the song (buffalo band) haha. I'm using messagepack for my projecet right now. but it doesn't support well for objects inside another objects( like having classes on list and these 2 are inside a dictionary). would you suggest a better serializer for my scenario? think i have to serialize multiple times for each layer.

Comment: @aidinjj I'm hugely biased, but it sounds like protobuf-net would be fine there, and trivial to add into an existing model

Comment: protobuf is good, but i don't know why it doesn't support hashtable data structure in c#. "No serializer defined for type: System.Collections.Hashtable"

Comment: anyway protobuf and messagepack are so much similar to each other.

Comment: @aidinjj because that is non-generic: it doesn't have defined shape - now try with `Dictionary<int, YourType>` or similar